# Failure to connect to Hortonworks Sandbox Hue (192 address) using VMWare Player

Tags: connectivity, hue, hortonworks-data-platform, vmware-player

I'm using VMWare Players for Window to connect to the Hortonworks Sandbox 2.2.  I get to the HDP 2.2 welcome screen that has tutorials, information, etc.  But when I try to connect to the actual sandbox via the 192 link they gave me, it will not allow me to connect to Hue, their GUI. When I click on the link I just get a chrome error "webpage not available".  I've opened it in Firefox and I get the same error.  At first I thought it was my work-issued computer, but I opened it on my (Windows) PC and get the same error.  What's the connectivity problem? I've also tried to SSH into it: To SSH into the VM and explore HDP 2.2 Sandbox from the command line and the username and password didn't work, either.

However, when I use Oracle Virtual Box via a 127 IP address, it works on my personal PC but not my laptop. Thanks in advance.  I've tried researching this on stackoverflow but no specific question like mine.

Comment: it seems a problem related to VMWare settings. Many people (even me) experimented the same problem. Unfortunately I don't know how to fix the issue

Comment: Am having exactly the same issue. nudro - were you able to resolve the VMWare problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem, what I did was I did `ifconfig` in VMWare for Hortonworks Sandbox and picked up the `inet addr:` pasted it on my web browser appending it with 8000 and it worked for me.

For example if `inet addr:` is `192.168.120.121` just type `192.168.120.121:8000` in your web browser.

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Virtualbox. It would not connect to hue gui (127.0.0.1:8000) on work laptop but worked fine on own laptop (connected to the static 127.0.0.1:8888 page on both no problem). 
Here's what worked for me to resolve on my work laptop: 
Powered off the VM. 
In Virtualbox I went to the settings for the VM and on the Network settings I set 'Attached to' dropdown to Bridged Adapter (thats the only thing i changed from the defaults but i suppose it might be worth checking that the network adapter listed in the 'Name' dropdown underneath the 'Attached to' dropdown is the one you are currently using to connect to the internet\router (in my case my wireless adapter)). 
Restarted the VM; 
When the VM was up I went into it, hit Alt+F5 to log in (as instructed on start-up screen), used 'root' as login and 'hadoop' as password; 
when logged in I entered 'ifconfig' at the prompt; on the ifconfig output displayed i looked for the internet address (inet addr) displayed for ethernet (eth0 in my case) and used that IP address instead of 127.0.0.1. in my web browser (in my case it was something like 192.163.41.3:8000). This thankfully did the trick.

I havent used VMPlayer but assume maybe are similar settings. Hope it helps!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the procedure above, because in my case url 127.0.0.1:8888 did not work. Alt+F5 and ifconfig showed eth0 = 192.168.56.102. Hue gui works now with address http://192.168.56.102 (or http://192.168.56.102:8888). I have Virtualbox and Sandbox 2.2.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer to the question.  If you have another question, post a new question.